# How to create a file inside a GCS bucket from a python list?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I'm using apache Airflow DAG.
In the DAG I'm using a python-operator.
Inside the operator my I'm getting some data inside a python list.
Now I want to save the data inside the list inside a txt file inside a google cloud storage bucket how can I do that?

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.getoutput('gsutil ls gs://my-bucket/*/1/')

#print(output)

li = list(output.split("\n"))
```

I want to create a text file containing the li on a gcs bucket.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic answer is to write li to a file in the file system.

```py
filehandle = open('temp.txt', 'w')
filehandle.write(li)
filehandle.close()
```

Then, upload to google

```py
output = subprocess.getoutput('gsutil cp temp.txt gs://my-bucket/')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `upload` function of [GcsHook](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/bb82cc0fbb7a6630eac1155d0c3b445dff13ceb6/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/gcs.py#L394) which uploads a local file or file data as string or bytes to Google Cloud Storage. In Airflow it's prefered to work with Hooks/Operators/Sensors as everything should already be configured for them.

I didn't test it but this should work:

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.gcs import GCSHook
def python_operator_callable():
    ...
    li = list(output.split("\n"))
    li_str = ', '.join(li) #data parameter accepts string or Bytes. Change this line to a format suitable for you
    hook = GcsHook(gcp_conn_id="conn_name")  # conn_name should be defined in Admin -> Connections
    hook.upload(
        bucket_name="you_bucket",
        object_name="temp.txt",
        data=li_str,
        encoding='utf-8')
```